# how to get phone number from kABPersonPhoneProperty with out any sybmbols?

Tags: iphone, ios

i am trying to get phone number from addressbook  , i am trying like this

```
ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
number.text = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, 0);
```

but it displaying numbers like (222)-456-3456

how can i get number without those symbols ( ) - etc

thanks in advance

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSString's method to get rid of ()-.

[Replacing Substrings](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003744)

1. – stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:
2. – stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:
3. – stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString: