# Getting just the phone number digits from kABPersonPhoneProperty in iOS

Tags: ios, utf-8, addressbook

I am unable to get the phone number string without UTF encoding it.. All the solutions in on this site assumes that there is no utf chars.. but I see utf chars :

```
NSLog(@"String = %@ %s",phoneNumber, [phoneNumber cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

shows up as:

> String = 919.1234567 919¬†1234567

How do i strip the utf parts in it?

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258653/how-to-get-phone-number-from-kabpersonphoneproperty-with-out-any-sybmbols?rq=1

Comment: yes. that assumes there is no utf7. this string has utf chars in it.. the 919.1234 is really not a dot but a utf \U00a0